# Issue with next metadata missing on Rest API Call

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I have a Pages Library which has a Managed Metadata Column called `Category`. I am using REST API to query this list.

I need to get the top 13 items and implement "Next" paging.

When I am accessing the API using `GET` I get the `__next` metadata in the result set.

```
_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Pages')/items?$top=13&orderby=Id%20asc
```

The issue here is that I need the label of the managed metadata and have no choice but to use `getItems()`

```
_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Pages')/getItems?$top=13&orderby=Id%20asc
```

With caml `query = ViewXml = "<View><Query></Query></View>"` just to returns all items.

On both queries, the `$top` works however in the `getItems()` I do not have `__next`. I am accessing SharePoint Online and making the call using `spHttpClient` from SharePoint Framework to retrieve the `RequestDigest`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If thelibrary doesn't have an insane amount. It might be easier and even faster to get All Items with minimum (nometadata) metadata upfront, filter them and  built a paged UX, and then fill in the missing metadata with more async calls. When a page loads a user doesn't interact with it in the first milsecs, users are slow..it might take 2 seconds for them to take in the page and interact with it. So things like onclick handlers and DIV data-attributes for filters are not required on first render. Same goes for images, everyone is used to images being loaded async. It is the essence of React

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. Even `<View><RowLimit>6</RowLimit><Query></Query></View>` does not provide any information on paging in the response.